# Rewriting the xml file in my application folder

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, deployment

Am using WPF-C#, when am closing my application i need to write some xml document. its located in my application folder (../Data/test.xml). its working while debuging. when i deploy my application cant able to access the xmlfile in the program files folder. how i can resolve this issue.. the following image is the exception http://img197.imageshack.us/i/errqu.jpg/

Answer (score 1):

Your users cannot modify a file located in `Program Files`.

If you have a configuration file you want to modify, you need to store it in the user's own `ApplicationData` folder, e.g.:

```
C:\Users\Bill\AppData\Local\SoftCo Software Inc\SuperApp\appconfig.xml
```

If you want standard users to be able to modify this config file, then your installation program is supposed to grant **Everyone** Full Control to the file. Your installation program is known to be running as an administrator, so it will have permissions to change permissions.

But you should not do that; this allows one user to alter program settings that will affect another user. These settings should be per-user (and stored in `%AppData%`, which the user already will have access to).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of [Windows UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control). You can fix the issue either

1. using Run As Administrator option, from right click menu in the application.
2. Modify the AppManifest file.
3. Change the file location user writable locations.

Comment: ya its working, i can able to rewrite the xml file. but everytime when am opening the application its popup UAC to grant access., any thing to avoid this??

Comment: No you can disable UAC in the machine. Otherwise no option, if you want to save the file in Program Files.